# Deprecated k8s API

Tags: api, kubernetes, upgrade, deprecated, kube-apiserver

Using different tools (kubent for example) I see that I have deprecated API in my cluster. For example

```
Type: Ingress Name: kibana  API: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

But when I open Ingress itself, I can see this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
  managedFields:
    - manager: Go-http-client
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

So, it shows that API of my Ingress is actually "v1", not "beta". But "managedFields" section indeed has "v1beta1" API. According to official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/server-side-apply/), this is server side API that should not be edited by user.

So, my question is - should/can I do anything with deprecated API in this "managedField"? Will there be any issues during upgrade to next k8s version? Because currently my GCP console shows that there will be problems.

Answer (score 3):

There will be no issue while upgrading your Kubernetes cluster to the latest version even if you have deprecated API version in the `managed field` in the ingress configuration.  The reason why you still see versions **“/v1beta1”** in the UI is because there are different parts of GKE that rely on both versions(v1 and v1beta1).

Between the two Kubernetes versions 1.19 and 1.21, both endpoints `networking.k8s.io/v1` and `extensions/v1beta1` are supported. They are functionally identical, and it is down to the given UI's preference for which version is displayed. So it won’t affect the functionality of your Ingress. As said, GKE clusters were created on [versions 1.22](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/apis-1-22#ingress-v122) and later stopped supporting extensions/v1beta1 and networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress.

Answer (score 1):

A detection of deprecated K8S APIs by 'kubent' tool can be performed in various modes:

- kubectl
- helm2
- helm3
- manifest file

According the [official documentation](https://github.com/doitintl/kube-no-trouble), the 'kubectl' mode ('-c=true') uses the following field to scan deperecated API on live cluster resources:

`kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration` - that's one of the reasons you probably see it as deprecated